# "On this occasion" vs. "during this occasion"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which one is correct?

> 1. I met my future wife on this very American traditional occasion.
> 2. I met my future wife during this very American traditional occasion.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical. Have you checked the dictionary definitions of "on" and "during"? If so, please edit your question to explain what you didn't understand, otherwise I think this question will be closed as "General reference".

Comment: Mr. Shiny - I understand the fundamental difference between the two prepositions though their stylistic usage in this very sentence was not clear to me. Mr. Google returned just two hits for "on this very traditional occasion" search and that is an immediate red flag. My question has been answered and thus the question can be closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***During*** is an unusual preposition in that it can only have an object that refers to a duration of [Time](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf) -- there are fewer than ten words in English that have exclusive time reference, and many of them come from the same root as *during*. It is also unusual in that it's almost never metaphorical. Objects of *during* will be interpreted as temporal references:

- *during the service, during dinner, during Summer, during the night*

Occasionally one must strain to interpret them that way in context:

- *during the aardvark, during B♭ Minor, during John Cassavetes, during NaOH*

That's the problem with using *during* with *occasion* as its object. Which temporal part of the "occasion" is being referred to? The dinner, the visiting, the travelling, or what? *Occasion* normally refers to a notation on a calendar -- a 2-Dimensional metaphor -- rather than something with a temporal duration of its own.

***On***, on the other hand, requires some two-dimensional surface as an object, and produces a location that is **above** and **in contact with** that surface:

- *on the sidewalk, on the lawn, on the desk[top], on the page, on the bed*

but *on* is more usually metaphorical, and will work with anything that can be [metaphorized](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) onto such a surface, which includes just about **anything**, at least if it can be printed on a sheet of paper:

- *on the subject of, on the Watson story, on the NYSE, on HBO, on Black Friday*

The last example shows how we use all three [Spatial](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf) dimensions to refer to Time in English. In general,

- Months and larger measures are Containers -- **3**-D: ***in*** 1949, **in** June, **in** this century
- Days are Surfaces -- **2**-D: ***on*** Thursday, **on** Thanksgiving, **on** this occasion
- Smaller measures are Points on a **1**-D line: ***at*** noon, **at** 12:03:45, **at** the moment of death.
  A special case is *at night*, which refers to some indefinite moment in the dark, especially to states or events repeated on multiple nights. The dark itself is a volume: *in the night/dark*.

That's why *on* is better for *occasion*.

Comment: On is *definitely* better for occasion, in every sense, even those that I couldn't articulate why (I hope it was clear in my answer). Maybe not, as I thought it was my preference for commemoration and fondness for the idea of marriage that might have biased my judgement. Your answer is awesome, by the way. I feel that mine is too ;o)  Mine is not analytically sound, merely anecdotal and culturally/ traditionally based. But in combination... we have it covered, so to speak!

Comment: I am very much amazed by this description. The mentioned rules above will certainly guide me through similar problems where the suggested answer cannot be simply justified by how well such phrase sound. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are grammatical. There are two differences in usage, though slight.

**Specificity**
The first sentence is slightly ambiguous:

> I met my future wife **on** this very American traditional occasion

A traditional occasion is presumed, by definition, to be a recurring event. You may have met your future wife on the occurrence of the event, many years ago, or last month. It may have been in Omaha, just as likely as in Guam.

The second sentence,

> I met my future wife **during** this very American traditional occasion

is more readily understood as a particular instance of the occasion. Both time and location are associated with specificity. So "during this occasion", would more likely imply "last month in Guam" versus "decades ago in Omaha", for example.

**Formality**
"During" rather than "on" is a less formal way of expressing something. For example, one would say, for a formal wedding invitation,

> Mr. and Mrs. Blah request the pleasure of your attendance **on** the
>   occasion of the marriage of their daughter, Blahbity.

I was surprised though, that "on" and "during" seem to be used interchangeably when I checked just now. The most common *English language* usages of "on the occasion of" were in **[Indian (Hindu, Muslim and Sikh)](http://www.regalcards.com/text_layouts.htm)** wedding invitations. There was merely one traditional Roman Catholic wedding guide that I found. It used "on the occasion of". Even a wedding announcement posted in the informal venue of the **[Yahoo! Groups Geophysics forum](http://dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/geophysics_au/message/681)** used "on the occasion of"! I am personally most familiar with American English, and Jewish wedding invitations. They use "on the occasion of".

Regarding more general usage of "on the occasion of", whether weddings or commemoration of formal events, **[Fatwa Online](http://www.fatwa-online.com/fataawa/marriage/maritalrelations/0051016.htm)** and **[Defender of Sunna](http://www.defenderofsunnah.com/fatwa/concise-fatwa/marriage/marital-relations/756-giving-the-wife-a-gift-on-the-occasion-of-the-wedding-anniversary)** use "on the occasion of" (all English language websites). Also, Fatwa Online makes the distinction that "on the occasion of" refers to the general case of the occasion, rather than a specific instance, to which I alluded to above.

Comment: Feral Oink, thank you for your answer as well. Your description has given me much an almost immediate insight into the differences in the meanings of the two sentences.

Comment: You are most welcome, @SunnyBoyNY I enjoyed answering your question, and hope that you will visit us again soon with additional questions (or answers)!